# PHP Code upgrade from 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: php

I have an old website that was written in PHP 5.2 but after upgrading PHP version, this has stopped working now.

This is the error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /var/www/vhosts/crm/httpdocs/libs/formval.class.php on line 212, referer: http://crm/admin/index.php
```

Code from formval.class.php

```
            // Are there any functions to run?
        if ($functions != '') {

            // Put the functions into an array.
            $functionArray = explode(',', $functions);

            // Loop through and run the functions.
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($functionArray); $i++) {

                $functionName = $functionArray[$i];

                switch ($functionName) {

                    case 'isNumber':
                        $callFunction = $this->isNumber($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    case 'isNumberND':
                        $callFunction = $this->isNumberND($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    case 'isNotZero':
                        $callFunction = $this->isNotZero($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    case 'isValidEmail':
                        $callFunction = $this->isValidEmail($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    case 'isValidDate':
                        $callFunction = $this->isValidDate($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    case 'isValidPassword':
                        $callFunction = $this->isValidPassword($data, &$errorMsg);
                        break;

                    default:
                        $callFunction = TRUE;

                }
```

This is line 212:

```
$callFunction = $this->isNumber($data, &$errorMsg);
```

Because this runs on Plesk 11.5, it does not let me install 5.2 with apache module, only CGI or FastCGI but neither make this site run.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you can't call by reference, use

`$callFunction = $this->isNumber($data, $errorMsg);`

instead of

`$callFunction = $this->isNumber($data, &$errorMsg);`

Also you'll have to change the isNumber function declaration from

```
public function isNumber($data, $errorMsg)
```

to

```
public function isNumber($data, &$errorMsg)
```

Comment: Thanks but looks like I am getting more and more errors! Now in hlpAdmin.class.php on line 202! Haha

Comment: @JustDima You need to replace all `&$errorMsg` with just `$errorMsg`

Comment: Yes that fine, thanks but it tells me this is also wrong: foreach($this->clause as $key => $value)

Comment: @jeroen Why would you say that this answer is incorrect.  If one were to simply change `&$errorMsg` in the function call to `$errorMsg` then the value would not be passed by reference without change the function definition to indicate that the parameter is to be passed by reference.  Basically in PHP 5.4 going forward they have standardized the behavior to only allow the pass by reference declaration to be made in the function definition.

Comment: @JustDima We are not going to be able to go through every single error you have in your migration in this single question. You should try to resolve all the errors you get in your logs as you encounter them. If you have a particular problem on an error that you can't resolve, then open a different question.

Comment: @jeroen How would you deduce that the function definition is correct from the code posted?  The function definition is not shown. The only possible change to the answer might be to say the function definition may need to be changed instead of must be changed.  It is important that the OP look at the function definition to make sure it has proper behavior.

Comment: @MikeBrant I need some coffee, didn't read correctly. Answer upvoted and mine deleted...

Comment: Thanks all, on to the next one!